# WPML makes my website 3 times slower when switch the language from default (English) to other (e.g. Arabic)

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, wpml

in English language the speed is ok but when I switch the language to Arabic it takes 3 times more time to load my site.

Comment: any error or warring in console r u checked ??

Comment: no there no error or warning

Comment: WPML is a premium product with support. You should try to contact them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install W3 Total Cache plugin, it will speed up your website by minifying the js, HTML, CSS files also include the cache feature that will surely enhance speed of your website.

[W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Answer (score -2):

Look over here i think it's helpfull

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/string-translation-slows-site-down/

Comment: Post a solution *here*, not a link to a forum thread. SO was specifically founded so developers wouldn't have to read through endless threads to discover some hidden hint somewhere.